# MySQL Select, join, comparing dates fails

Tags: mysql

I have these two tables:

```
DateRanges

some_id   start_date    end_date
---------------------------------
1         2012-12-01   2012-12-15
1         2013-01-01   2013-01-15
3         2013-01-03   2013-01-10


Items

id      name
----------------
1     Some name
2     Other name
3     So on...
```

What I try to achieve is to get, for each element in `Items` table, the biggest `start_date` (ignoring the smaller dates/date ranges for that Item) and check if the current date is in that range, like in the next table (let's say today's 02 January 2013):

```
id       name          TodayIsInTheRange
---------------------------------------------
1      Some name             true
2      Other name            false
3      So on...              false
```

I have tried to obtain the 3rd table with the next query:

```
SELECT A.*, (B.`start_date` <= CURRENT_DATE AND CURRENT_DATE <= B.`end_date`) AS `TodayIsInTheRange`                                            
FROM `Items` as A                                                
LEFT JOIN `DateRanges` as B ON                                            
A.id = B.some_id
SORT BY B.`end_date` DESC
```

But with this query my items repeat themselves because I have two records in `DateRanges` for the same item.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try to use `GROUP BY` and `MAX` function. The first provide you only one row for each item.id, the second tell you if there is at least one date in your range

```
SELECT A.*, MAX(B.`start_date` <= CURRENT_DATE AND CURRENT_DATE <= B.`end_date`) AS `TodayIsInTheRange`                                            
FROM `Items` as A                                                
LEFT JOIN `DateRanges` as B ON                                            
A.id = B.some_id
GROUP BY A.id
ORDER BY B.`end_date` DESC
```

Answer (score 2):

I use SQL Server, but I think something like this should be pretty close:

```
SELECT 
    I.Id, 
    I.Name,
    (DR.start_date <= CURRENT_DATE AND CURRENT_DATE <= DR.end_date) AS `TodayIsInTheRange`
FROM `Items` AS I
    LEFT JOIN 
        (SELECT Some_Id, MAX(Start_Date) as MaxStartDate 
        FROM `DateRanges`
        GROUP BY Some_ID) AS HDR ON I.Id = HDR.Some_Id
    LEFT JOIN `DateRanges` AS DR ON HDR.Some_Id = DR.Some_Id AND HDR.MaxStartDate = DR.Start_Date
```

Answer (score 1):

```
select * from items join date_ranges dr0 on items.id = dr0.some_id
  where start_date = 
       (select max(start_date) from date_ranges dr1 where dr0.some_id = dr1.some_id);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT 
  a.*, 
  ( b.start_date <= CURRENT_DATE 
  AND CURRENT_DATE <= b.end_date ) AS TodayIsInTheRange 
FROM 
    Items AS a 
  LEFT JOIN 
    ( SELECT some_id, MAX(start_date) AS start_date
      FROM DateRanges
      GROUP BY some_id
    ) AS m
    JOIN 
      DateRanges AS b 
        ON b.some_id = m.some_id
      ON a.id = m.some_id
ORDER BY b.end_date DESC ;
```